# Producer consumer termination

Tags: java, concurrency, producer-consumer

I am currently studying concurrent programming patterns. Consider the solution to the producer consumer problem with bounded buffer using semaphores, presented on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem#Implementations).

What if, at some point, the producer says: this is the last item I'm making. How could I make the program terminate?(the consumer will still wait until it is informed that there is something in the buffer).

Similarly, what if the consumer says: I don't want to consume anymore. How can the producer be informed, so that the program exits? (the producer is waiting to have an available spot to put something).

Comment: Give references of producer to consumer and vice versa.

Answer (score 4):

From [Java Concurrency in Practice Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601) 7.2.3

`Another way to convince a producer consumer service to shut down is with a poison pill: a recognizable object placed 
on the queue that means "when you get this, stop."`

Go through the 7th chapter of this book `Cancellation and Shutdown`

Comment: With this solution it is easy to see how a producer can tell the consumer to stop, but what about the opposite?

Comment: Exactly. What if the consumer stops accepting, and the producer doesn't know an waits for the consumer to accept?

Comment: What about using monitors...?

Answer (score 2):

You can have the producer terminate the consumer by placing a poison message in the queue, when the consumer receives the message it recognises the message is a shutdown from the producer, and shuts itself down accordingly.

Communication from consumer to producer in the given scenario is not possible, you would have to create another channel of communication, as communication is only one way currently.

You could use an Exchanger instance for direct (queue-less) communication, and then the poison message can be passed both ways, though you now have a directly linked process pair rather than independent producer/consumer pair.

Finally, you could register all the producers and consumers with a single manager, that they all have a reference to, any producer/consumer can request a shutdown, which sets a flag, and then all check the flag, or respond to InterruptedException and the manager sends an interrupt to each of them.